# Python, baixando arquivo em determinado dia e horário

Tags: python, web-scraping

Estou querendo estruturar um programa em Python que baixe arquivos (mangás) de determinado site uma vez por semana. Estou treinando, realizei o curso de *web scraping*, mas estou perdido de como realizar estas requisições. Tomei como exemplo, o código desta página

```
import urllib2
import requests

url = 'http://www.carlissongaldino.com.br/modules/pubdlcnt/pubdlcnt.php?file=http://www.carlissongaldino.com.br/sites/default/files/o-fantasma-da-opera.pdf&nid=1287'

print "baixando com urllib"
urllib.urlretrieve(url, "o-fantasma-da-opera-u.pdf")

print "baixando com urllib2"
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = f.read()
with open("o-fantasma-da-opera-u2.pdf", "wb") as code:
    code.write(data)

print "baixando com requests"
r = requests.get(url)
with open("o-fantasma-da-opera-r.pdf", "wb") as code:
    code.write(r.content)
```

Ela ensina a baixar determinado arquivo utilizando as seguintes bibliotecas. Vejo um padrão, acho que daria certo, preciso apenas implementar o dia e o horário. Estou perdido nesta parte. Como podem me ajudar a elucidar este caso?

Comment: Por quê não utiliza uma tarefa agendada via CRON?

Comment: E, como seria esta utilização?

Comment: [Usando cron e crontab para agendar tarefas](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Usando-cron-e-crontab-para-agendar-tarefas)

Comment: Sou novato na área de programação, estou realizando experimentos. Quero evoluir este programa. 
Este codigo que tomei como exemplo, está valido para esta tarefa que quero realizar?

Comment: Posso utilizar este cron e crontab neste programa já estruturado?

Comment: Então, o código que colocou faz 3 vezes a mesma coisa, com módulos diferentes. A mais simples é a última, com `requests`. E sim, tendo o programa funcionando, basta agendar sua execução na CRON que ele executará sempre no horário definido.

Comment: Bacana! E, como entraria este cron no programa, ainda não tinha utilizado esta solicitação. Primeira vez que a vejo.